# Tetravalent graph invariant: Vassiliev in disguise?

Tags: knot-theory

[image: Da Rules]

Let's start with a virtual link, just that it has no over- and undercrossings, but simple nodes. Random example (A). For the virtual crossings, the usual laws hold (B). Also as usual, loose loops drop off (C).

Now the node shall be fully antisymmetric - that's why I didn't draw it as a simple dot (rotation D, crossing legs E, as an immediate corollary F; actually D follows from E too).

Now that we defined the basics, we may assume some skein relations hold. The most simple and generic (unless we go for the Kauffman polynomial analog, but that gives *too* trivial results!) is G. ("Most generic" as in the symmetry laws dictate the form, and we could rescale the value of a node.) Obviously this isn't enough to reduce all virtual links, we also must do something with triangles (H). If we assume this reduces to simpler graphs, my computations say this is effectively an invariant based on the Lie algebra $B_3$.

I wouldn't be surprised if I just constructed a Vassiliev invariant in disguise. Is it? Has there already been work on this construction? (After all, it is well-known that a semisimple Lie algebra comes with an antisymmetric 4-tensor.)